# prepare for segue.. from UITableView to DetailView with parse Objects

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, segue

trying to get from my UITableViewController to the detail view controller with these PFObjects...thanks in advance!

error i can't seem to reconcile..."Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String'"

I want the queried objects to present on the detail view controller...

here is my query and my prepare for segue...i can't seem to access the objects in the prepare for segue...

```
    var customerName = [String]()
    var customerAddress = [String]()

  var query = Pfuser.query
  query.whereKey("userId",equalTo:adminFollowingUser)
  query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (adminObjects, error) -> Void in

          if let objects = adminObjects {

            for object in objects {

  self.customerName.append(object["customerName"] as! String)
  self.customerAddress.append(object["customerStreetAddress"] as! String)
```

// Here is the prepare for segue....

```
      override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:
      AnyObject?)
      {
       if (segue.identifier == "thesePools")
      {

       let employeeDetailVC: EmployeeDetailViewController =  segue.destinationViewController
    as! EmployeeDetailViewController
  // indexPath is set to the path that was tapped


let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

  let customerNameLabel = self.customerName[indexPath!.row]
  let customerAddressLabel = self.customerAddress[indexPath!.row]
 employeeDetailVC.customerString = customerNameLabel
  employeeDetailVC.addressString = customerAddressLabel
```

here is my detail view controller receiving the Strings.

```
       //DetailViewController  

   var customerString = String()
   var addressString = String()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.customerLabel.text = customerString
self.addressLabel.text = addressString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var currentObject = String() is a string and you set it to a string in the prepareForSegue.This should do the trick: 
self.customerTextField.text = curentObject
And remove all the other stuff.

Comment: i got all the errors out but when i click the cell it still won't segue..i triple checked the segue name, deleted and redid it triple checked the class name of the destination view controller...not sure what else to do..i would say this is the answer...but its still not working :(

Comment: Have you made the segue in the storyboard? How did you make it? Also if you use the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" be sure it is not "didDeSelectRowAtIndexPath", that is a mistake often made. Also you have to "option click" on the table view and draw it to the view controller both for data source and delegate and you have to implement the tableviewcontroller delegate. See more here https://medium.com/@ronm333/a-simple-table-view-example-in-swift-cbf9a405f975

Comment: dude that article was awesome! figured it out with that article! thanks so much for url :)

Comment: Your welcome, consider marking the answer as "answered" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try that

```
    let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! CustomerDetailViewController
    var indexPath :NSIndexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        var object  = self.CustomerName[indexPath.row] as! String 
           nav.currentobject = object
```

Comment: getting the same error with the your code..."does not have member named objects"...for some reason I'm not able to access the objects in my query....can i nest the prepare for segue in my query so it knows what objects its getting?

Comment: objects is the array that you have save the things you query from parse you know that right. in your case it should be **customerName** or **customAddress**

Comment: i update the code it should be the name of the array you are using

Comment: I'm having issues with casting... since i saved them to the array as strings...i can't cast them as PFObjects  with var object :PFObject = self.customerName[indexPath.row] as! PFObject. i think were close!

Comment: var object = self.customerName[indexPath.row] as! String  try that

Comment: i updated the code for what i currently have...almost there...just somethings off with trying to get a string out of an indexed string...wierd..still researching it

Comment: what kind of datatype did you set up in the detail ViewController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83816/discussion-between-steve-derienzo-and-lamar).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a PFQueryTableViewController. 
This is a UI object that is provided by Parse and loads data from your class 50x faster.

Here is an example of how to create it:

```
    import UIKit

class YourTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

// Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    self.parseClassName = "yourClass"

    self.textKey = "yourObject"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false
}

// Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "yourClass")
    query.orderByAscending("yourObject")


    return query
}

//override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CustomTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = CustomTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell

    cell.info.text = object["info"] as String


    // Date for cell subtitle
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let dateForText = object["date"] as NSDate
    cell.date.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateForText)

    return cell
}

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as YourDetailViewController

    // Pass the selected object to the destination view controller.
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        let row = Int(indexPath.row)
        detailScene.currentObject = objects[row] as? PFObject
    }
}
```

At the end make sure to also created a custom cell class.